# Setting "enabled" to false on a Vaadin 8 `NativeSelect` widget does not alter its appearance nor stop it from popping-up

Tags: vaadin, popupmenu, vaadin8

In a Vaadin 8.1.3 app, I have a [`NativeSelect`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/ui/NativeSelect.html) component on a layout, with a [`CheckBox`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/ui/CheckBox.html) next to it. The listener on the checkbox calls `setEnabled` on the popup-menu (the `NativeSelect`), passing true or false.

If **false**, I expected the widget to be dimmed in appearance, per the documentation. And I expected the popup menu to no longer pop up when clicked. Both of these expectations were not met. The widget does not change in appearance whether enabled or not. The widget continues to pop-up a menu when clicked. That's bad.

When `enabled` is set to **false**, choosing an item from the menu no longer triggers an event. The listener that responds to a value change on the menu no longer runs. That's good.

Is this a bug on the `NativeSelect`? The [`NativeSelect::setEnabled`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.3/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setEnabled-boolean-) method documentation promises:

> … The user can not interact with disabled components, which are shown with a style that indicates the status, usually shaded in light gray color.  …

Is there some other way to dim the appearance of the `NativeSelect` and disable the display of its menu?

In summary, I am looking for three behaviors on a disabled popup menu:

- Grayed-out/dimmed appearance
- No longer pops up when clicked
- Generates no events when clicked

The `setEnabled` command seems to promise all three bullets but delivers only the last bullet.

I am surprised by this behavior, given that this is a "native" HTML object. The `select` HTML object is defined to have a `disable` attribute in both old HTML as well as HTML5. This attribute has both effects I need: alter display, and make un-clickable. See [this explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_select_disabled.asp) and [this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_disabled) of the HTML `select` widget being disabled.

I filed [Issue # 9956](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/9956).

Answer (score 1):

It's because Vaadin [Component interface](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html) delivers two methods to adjust component: `setEnabled()` and **`setReadOnly()`** - which you are actually looking for.

Here is my solution for you:

```
    NativeSelect<String> nativeSelect = new NativeSelect<String>() {
        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled)
        {
            super.setEnabled(enabled);
            setReadOnly(!enabled);
            if (enabled)
                removeStyleName("transparency");
            else
                addStyleName("transparency");
        }};
```

---

[Add](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-creating.html) to css:

```
.transparency {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Not quite a full solution: The widget is not dimmed or grayed out. Looks normal, with no visual hint of being unavailable. Calling `setReadOnly` solves my second bullet. Calling `setEnabled` solves my third bullet. But my first bullet, visual display, is not yet solved.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I found that calling `setVisibleItemCount()` with number greater than 1, and then setting Component to ReadOnly results with dimmed appearance of NativeSelect. Maybe Vaadin assumes that if you want to have only 1 element visible you would use [ComboBox](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.5/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html)

Comment: Please check my last edit - hope this solution will suffice ;)

Comment: That CSS idea is a nice workaround. I would use a different name than `opacity` as that seems likely to confuse. Opacity property in CSS was not always supported by browsers, but it looks like the modern browsers of the last several years do according to [this report](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp).

Answer (score 0):

## Right and Wrong

You seem to be wrong about the `NativeSelect` popping up when clicked if disabled and/or read-only.

You seem to be right about the `NativeSelect` breaking its contract to display a graying-out or similar visual cue if *disabled* (“shown with a style that indicates the status, usually shaded in light gray color”).

### Example app

Here is a complete example Vaadin 8.1.3/8.1.4 in a single class.

```java
package com.example.vaadin.checkboxexample;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.data.HasValue;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent a browser window
 * (or tab) or some part of a html page where a Vaadin application is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This method is intended to be
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize non-component functionality.
 *
 */
@Theme ( "mytheme" )
public class MyUI extends UI
{

    @Override
    protected void init ( VaadinRequest vaadinRequest )
    {
        // Widgets
        List < String > strings = Arrays.asList( "This" , "That" , "The other" , "Yet another" );

        // Default
        final NativeSelect < String > popupDefault = new NativeSelect( "Default:" , new ArrayList<>(strings) );
        popupDefault.setValue( strings.get( 3 ) );
        popupDefault.addValueChangeListener( ( HasValue.ValueChangeListener < String > ) valueChangeEvent ->
        {  System.out.println( "popupDefault selected: " + valueChangeEvent.getValue( ) ); } );

        // Disabled
        final NativeSelect < String > popupDisabled = new NativeSelect( "Disabled:" , new ArrayList<>(strings) );
        popupDisabled.setValue( strings.get( 3 ) );
        popupDisabled.addValueChangeListener( ( HasValue.ValueChangeListener < String > ) valueChangeEvent ->
        {  System.out.println( "popupDisabled selected: " + valueChangeEvent.getValue( ) ); } );
        popupDisabled.setEnabled( false );

        // ReadOnly
        final NativeSelect < String > popupReadOnly = new NativeSelect( "ReadOnly:" , new ArrayList<>(strings) );
        popupReadOnly.setValue( strings.get( 3 ) );
        popupReadOnly.addValueChangeListener( ( HasValue.ValueChangeListener < String > ) valueChangeEvent ->
        {  System.out.println( "popupReadOnly selected: " + valueChangeEvent.getValue( ) ); } );
        popupReadOnly.setReadOnly( true );

        // Disabled and  ReadOnly
        final NativeSelect < String > popupDisabledAndReadOnly = new NativeSelect( "Disabled & ReadOnly:" , new ArrayList<>(strings) );
        popupDisabledAndReadOnly.setValue( strings.get( 3 ) );
        popupDisabledAndReadOnly.addValueChangeListener( ( HasValue.ValueChangeListener < String > ) valueChangeEvent ->
        {  System.out.println( "popupDisabledAndReadOnly selected: " + valueChangeEvent.getValue( ) ); } );
        popupDisabledAndReadOnly.setEnabled( false );
        popupDisabledAndReadOnly.setReadOnly( true );

        // Layout
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout( );
        layout.addComponents( popupDefault , popupDisabled , popupReadOnly , popupDisabledAndReadOnly );
        setContent( layout );
    }

    @WebServlet ( urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true )
    @VaadinServletConfiguration ( ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false )
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet
    {
    }
}
```

Here is a screen-shot when run in *Safari Technology Preview* browser. Same behaviors seen in *Vivaldi* browser.

- The first popup-menu does indeed popup when clicked; the others three do not. (Good)
- Note how at least the second and fourth should appear visually grayed-out but do not. (Bad)

[image: screen shot of four NativeSelect widgets, the first is default, second is disabled, third is read-only, and fourth is both disabled and read-only.]